# document.write to different page and stay

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

Is there a way to document.write variables on a separate page and have them stay there even if you refresh both pages?  I kind of want the separate page to work as a database for the vars on the first page.

CODE:

MAIN.JS

```
        function timeMsg()
        {
        var t=setTimeout("alertMsg()",500);
        }
        function alertMsg()
        {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="one" id="one" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';
            }

        function changeSet() {
            var s=setTimeout("alertYea()",500);
            var a = document.getElementById("one").value;
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">2</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '9264';
            document.getElementById('one1').innerHTML = a;
        }
        function alertYea() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="two" id="two" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet2()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet2() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea2()",500);
            var b = document.getElementById("two").value;
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">3</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '38671';
            document.getElementById('two2').innerHTML = (b);
        }

        function alertYea2() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="three" id="three" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet3()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet3() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea3()",500);
            var c = document.getElementById("three").value;
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">4</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '938263';
            document.getElementById('three3').innerHTML = (c);
        }

        function alertYea3() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="four" id="four" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet4()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet4() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea4()",500);
            var d = document.getElementById("four").value;
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">5</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '8351032';
            document.getElementById('four4').innerHTML = (d);
        }

        function alertYea4() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="five" id="five" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet5()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet5() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea5()",500);
            var e = document.getElementById("five").value;
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">6</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '02619815';
            document.getElementById('five5').innerHTML = (e);
        }

        function alertYea5() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="six" id="six" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet6()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet6() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea6()",500);
            var f = document.getElementById("six").value;
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">7</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '274619523';
            document.getElementById('six6').innerHTML = (f);
        }

        function alertYea6() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="seven" id="seven" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet7()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet7() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea7()",500);
            var g = document.getElementById("seven").value;
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">8</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '1681324849';
            document.getElementById('seven7').innerHTML = (g);
        }

        function alertYea7() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="eight" id="eight" type="text"></input></br><input id="answer" type="button" value="Next" onClick="changeSet8()"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }

        function changeSet8() {
            var a=setTimeout("alertYea8()",500);
            var h = document.getElementById("eight").value;
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<p id="bumper">9</p>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = '48372605629';
            emailData.data.value = h;
            document.getElementById('eight8').innerHTML = (h);
        }

        function alertYea8() {
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<h3>Times up partner, what were they?</h3></br><input name="nine" id="nine" type="text"></input></br><p id="send"></p><input id="answer" name="submit" type="button" onclick="finals()" value="Next"/>');
            document.getElementById('number').value = 'no cheating...';

            }
        function finals() {
            var i = document.getElementById("nine").value;
            document.getElementById('remember').innerHTML = ('<div id="send"><form method="POST" enctype="text/plain" name="emailData"></br><input id="data" type="text" size="20" name="data"><br><input type="submit" value="Submit and continue to letters!"></form></div>');
            document.getElementById('nine9').innerHTML = (i);
        }
```

page w/ values:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Memory Test</title>
        <link href="bio.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="../jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="timeMsg()">
        <div id="container">
            <h3>The numbers are...</h3>
            <input id="number" type="text" value="495"/>
            <div id="remember">

            </div>
            <div id="email">
                <input id="a"></input>
                <input id="b"></input>
                <input id="c"></input>
                <input id="d"></input>
                <input id="e"></input>
                <input id="f"></input>
                <input id="g"></input>
                <input id="h"></input>
                <input id="i"></input>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

pg for data:

Comment: Re. "a database for the vars on the first page", can't you do that with a separate js file?

Comment: i don't know how, i have an external js but im not sure if the information will stay there or if it will just disappear if i refresh or something.

Comment: Sessions might be an option too - refreshing will kill anything none session/cookie based

Comment: i didn't think of cookies, i'll try that but im also posting my code because for some reason the values don't even show up in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following to store data between refreshes:

- `window.name`
- `document.cookie`
- `location.hash`
- `window.localStorage`
- `window.sessionStorage`
- `document.forms`
- `window.opener`